# Remove the vertical padding from the <kbd> tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

I think the <kbd>k</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> tag's vertical padding is too large to use them inline with other text. Once your text wraps onto multiple lines, <kbd>k</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>-tagged elements' vertical padding makes them visually overflow onto the lines before and after, making the entire paragraph harder to read.

I suggest changing the padding value to "0px 2px", instead of the "2px 2px" it is, currently. This retains the horizontal padding to easily recognize it as a keystroke, but removes the vertical padding to prevent characters from encroaching on the other lines.

Comment: Related, [our neighborhood badp's attempt to resolve this same issue with lists](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58760/kbd-yes-still-kbd-doesnt-play-nice-with-lists "It got bydesign'd because it was posted as a bug report").

Answer (score 3):

This issue was resolved when the `<kbd>` style was made consistent with a new style across the SE network.

See also: [Could we have the new <kbd> tag?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4633/28182)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of messing with the padding, you can just add the `display: inline-block` attribute to the `kdb` pseudo-tag.

What's happening here is that we're telling the browser to display the `kbd` element inline (fits the text), but also allow it to retain their block-level characteristics (fits the element container).