# Could we have the new <kbd> tag?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

Recently, `<kbd>` tags on the trilogy sites and I think Apple as well were [updated to look less ugly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-intrusive/1945#1945).

[image: screenshot - kbd old style] vs. [image: screenshot - kbd new style]

<kbd>I am in favor of less ugly. Can we have it to match our sweet new design?</kbd>

Comment: TBH I find the new version harder to read, though the fact that it works more often is a definite plus.

Comment: I prefer the old ones...

Comment: This hasn't been actioned nor `[status-declined]`, and the two answers are joke answers at best... Do we need to poke some people over at SE?

Comment: We're in the process of updating arqade's LESS(CSS) soon and I'll add this change in.

Answer (score 7):

Can we have `<kbd>` to be made to look more like arcade buttons? Most of the time it's used it's for a single character at a time.

E.g.:

[image]

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tzarbj36/2/)

Comment: This would fit well with our overall 16-bit-esque theme

Answer (score 6):

Down with the new-style <kbd>! Keep the old one! Or at least keep the serif font!

The biggest appeal of the kbd tag is that it's completely unambiguous: press <kbd>1</kbd>, then <kbd>I</kbd>, then <kbd>l</kbd>, and Dwarf Fortress will do something clever and/or terrible. Switching that to a sans-serif font makes those keys unclear, and <kbd> should be utterly beyond confusion.

I would be fine with changing the border around the letter to take up a bit less space, but using a sans-serif font is just wrong. We theoretically could force all letters to upper-case, but it's still going to be ambiguous when an "I" shows up by itself in an answer, and there's no other hint that all keyboard entries are upper-case.

Comment: Ah, I now get what you mean, so I have removed my downvote. Ran some tests on Meta.SE if anyone's interested (feel free to edit and play around): http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250518/179041

Comment: Dunno if they updated the font, but on mobile at least, I 1 and l are all showing up with serif font

Answer (score -2):

Fix this castle! (shamelessly [robbed from here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-intrusive/131634#131634)).  It looks better than the old style castle anyways.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Answer (score -8):

But then we would not have an awesome KBD castle. And that would be WRONG.

[OUR PRINCESS IS IN ANOTHER CASTLE!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1974)

Comment: Your castle does not like our site.

Comment: Also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131634/138509

Comment: Wow, tough crowd

Comment: @JuanManuel This is Gaming, we don't take kindly to fun around here.

Comment: Unless it's in question titles.